# rails 3.1 - How to fix this query filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-3.1

I am using

```
 @events = @user.events.where('finishDate >= ?', Time.now)
```

to retrieve the events from a certain user. Before displaying it I want to filter by date, and get rid off old one. Thus, finishDate column belong to Events. However it gives an error style "could not find 'finishDate' column in users_events table' (the table of the relationship)

How can I tell the query to look in events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my surprise, the problem was not that the query was filtering in the wrong table. It was the name of the filtering column what was giving the error.

I renamed the table column from

```
finishDate
```

to

```
finish_date
```

and worked perfectly!